# Using @types/angular as global

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm currently trying to update my angular 1 application from `typings` to `@types`.

First I got following error message:

```
Identifier 'angular' must be imported from a module
```

After some searching I found out, that angular isn't accessible globally anymore. Or anleast I didn't find out how...

---

With `typings`, `angular` was global and I could use it without imports or anything. My problem is, that an import of angular, like this:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
```

breaks my application: Unfortunately `SystemJS` is now trying to load angular and because of this it's not available when `ui-bootstrap` and other libs are loaded with script tags.

To fix this, I would have to rewrite a huge part of the build-pipeline. So I'm asking again: Is there another way to use angular with `TypeScript 2` and `@types`, that doesn't end in a `require('angular')`?

Comment: having the same prolem right now. Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. Do this and everything will work finr.

```
import * as _angular_ from 'angular';

declare global {
  const angular: typeof _angular_;
}
```